# biblatex biber texlive Mac OS Catalina 10.15.2

Tags: bibtex, texlive, biber, texlive-2019

The problem:

I have been using Overleaf recently to avoid compatibility problems, but a recent update on their side means that I cannot use files with biber for some reason. I went back to my mac version, and upgraded TexLive using

> sudo tlmgr update --self --all

just in case. All ran smoothly.

Running the following test file:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{test.bib}
\begin{document}
I doubt that there is any useful information here~\cite{wikibook}.

~\cite{wombat2016}.
~\cite[9]{lion2010}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with a simple bib file using either TeXshop or line commands create the following problem:

```
0] Config.pm:304> INFO - This is Biber 2.14
[0] Config.pm:307> INFO - Logfile is 'test.blg'
[91] biber-darwin:322> INFO - === Wed Jan  8, 2020, 16:05:07
[103] Biber.pm:415> INFO - Reading 'test.bcf'
[120] Utils.pm:320> ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 1.6, expected version 3.7.
This means that your biber (2.14) and biblatex () versions are incompatible.
See compat matrix in biblatex or biber PDF documentation.
[120] Biber.pm:132> INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

I have looked through the message boards for a few hours. There is an incompatibility between bibtex files and biber. Sadly, I tried to update bibtex using tlmgr [using uninstall and install], but that was not possible:

```
texlive % sudo tlmgr uninstall bibtex       
tlmgr: saving backups to /usr/local/texlive/2019/tlpkg/backups
tlmgr: not removing bibtex.x86_64-darwin, needed by bibtex
tlmgr: not removing bibtex, needed by collection-basic
tlmgr: no packages removed.
tlmgr: action remove returned an error; continuing.
tlmgr: An error has occurred. See above messages. Exiting.
```

A little more sleuthing appears to indicate that there is a problem with the bibtex files here:

`/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty`

The file looks OLD:

```
% $Id: biblatex.sty,v 1.6 2011/07/29 19:21:28 lehman stable $

% Copyright (c) 2006-2011 Philipp Lehman.
%
% Permission is granted to copy, distribute and/or modify this
% software under the terms of the LaTeX Project Public License
% (LPPL), version 1.3.
%
% The LPPL maintenance status of this software is
% 'author-maintained'.
%
```

Yet there does not seem to be a way to install that particular set.

When I try to update texlive, it tells me it is well updated. But clearly it is NOT!

I have also tried removing the files in `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty`
and calling the tlmgr, but it thinks that everything is installed fine, so that does not work.

I have now spent about 4 hours on this. Hopefully you all smart people can help how to report eh biblatex.sty file, which appears to be wrong.

Thank you.

Comment: Remove any `biblatex` stuff from your `texmf-local`. Files there will be found first, and will override the base installation.

Comment: Curious that you tried to delete the new but not the old file. The biblatex in texmf-local is obviously old and a problem, so delete it.

Comment: Oh you beautiful people of the internet. I love you. worked perfectly. I had tried to delete the old one (renamed the biblatex something else), but that did not work. Removing the whole texmf-local did the trick. Toodles!

Comment: @SimoneH I'll turn my comment into an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 1):

In general, unless you know what you're doing, you shouldn't need to have files in your `texmf-local` directory. The TeX programs search for files in an order starting from most local to least local, (roughly: local directory  < user level `texmf` < `texmf-local` < `texmf-dist`) and local files will preempt distribution level files.

At some point you may have installed `biblatex` into your `texmf-local` folder. For any package that is part of the regular distribution, this is almost certainly a bad idea, since the local version will be loaded, and will be immune from updates (as you discovered.)

So you can safely remove it from there, and the problem should disappear. Typically you don't need to have anything in `texmf-local`, and for custom packages it's usually preferred to use the user level local `texmf` folder ( `~/Library/texmf` on Mac; `~/texmf` on Linux).

Comment: Accepted & closed.